# Admin Site’s “VIEW ON SITE” URL Incorrect

Tags: url, django-models, django-admin

I recently discovered Django Admin's VIEW ON SITE function, which is pretty cool. I defined `get_absolute_url` in my model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

When I hover the link in the admin, I see this URL: `http://localhost:8000/adminr/10/4/` and when I click it, it takes me to here (after redirect?): `http//localhost:8000/product/<name>` (note the missing colon in the URL).

I can define `view_on_site` in my `ProductAdmin` and get things to work:

```
def view_on_site(self, obj):
    return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'slug': obj.slug})
```

Assuming this just uses the "site" I've defined in the admin already (for domain), which is `http://localhost:8000`. What am I missing? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted on the Django forum and got the answer:

https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/admin-sites-view-on-site-url-incorrect/4602

Turns out I was specifying the wrong thing in the Domain Name field in the Django admin. I had the URL scheme included like this: `http://localhost:8000`

And the field actually wants this: `localhost:8000`

The validation doesn't catch this, so this is why I never noticed it before.